# Trouble finding xpath for mouseover tooltip on Cookie Clicker (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, tooltip, bots

I am trying to make a Selenium cookie clicker bot and I need to find the cookies produced per second by each "production" (grannies, clickers, etc.)

[image: see here]

However, the tooltip only shows when the mouse is hovering over, and I am having trouble identifying the correct xpath to reference the value.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked in DOM, from where te tooltip text value is coming? It could be the "title" attribute.

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner what do you mean by DOM?

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML or URL of web site if that's not private ?

Comment: http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

thank you for looking into it!

Comment: If it's a website, open the website on chrome. Right click on desired Element. Click on Inspect -> Share the HTMl code, which you see in DEV Tool.

Comment: @RajKamal this is what I am trying, but i can find the price of the upgrade, which has an ID code, but i am having trouble finding the ID for "0.1" from "each cursor produces 0.1 cookies per second" as depicted in the linked picture

Comment: from my network it is blocked from my internet provider, don't know the exact reason why.

Comment: the tooltip only shows up when I mouse hover it so I can't inspect it :(

Comment: Are you looking for a value which will be displayed on Mouse Hover on Right side text "Cursor with text below 155.303 million"?

Comment: and tooltip text also displays value 155.303 million.. right?

Comment: @RajKamal the value from 
"each cursor produces ____ cookies per second" 

from the tooltip that pops up when you mousehover over the 155.303 million

Comment: the tooltip text is the left half of the attatched image

Comment: if that is a title attribute which @RajKamal suspected : the you can use this code `String hoverValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).getAttribute("title");`

Comment: @cruisepandey yes but I am having trouble finding the actual xpath

Comment: I cant find the associated id or class for the tooltip which is the problem im having

Comment: @cruisepandey They are not using title attribute here:

Comment: @GeorgeXu, Check my answer. Code is in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the website [Link](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker) and I was able to get the xpath for the cookies per second text.

You can get is using xpath: `//*[@id="tooltip"]/div/div[7]/b[1]`

Code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='tooltip']/div/div[7]/b[1]")).text;
```

Comment: I would give u the upvote but I dont have enough reputation :(